# MS Access Query - display data for each month over multiple years as columns

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013, vba

OK, I am very new at this and have been googling things for the past few hours and have not found anything. Maybe I'm not looking for the right thing or I'm not looking hard enough but I am here now.

I have 3 calculations I need to do for each month (over 5 years) to be displayed as columns (3*12*5=180 total columns). I have mock formulas in Excel:

**Fraction of Month** `=IF(AND(FEStart>=s01Y15,FEStart<=e01Y15),IF(FEStart=s01Y15, 1, ((e01Y15-(FEStart))+1)/DAY(e01Y15)),IF(AND(FEEnd>=s01Y15,FEEnd<=e01Y15),IF(FEEnd=e01Y15, 1, ((FEEnd)-(s01Y15))/DAY(e01Y15)),IF(FEEnd<=e01Y15, 0, IF(FEStart<=s01Y15,1,0))))`

**Year of Person** `=IF(AND(FEStart>=s01Y15,FEStart<=e01Y15),1,IF(AND(FEEnd>=s01Y15,FEEnd<=e01Y15),INT((s01Y15-FEStart)/365)+1,IF(FEEnd<= e01Y15, 0, IF(FEStart<=s01Y15,INT((s01Y15-FEStart)/365)+1,0))))`

**Monthly Salary** `=([Fraction of Month]*(SF/12))*(1.03^([Year of Person]-1))`

Where

- FEStart is the Start Date of the Person (entered by user)
- s01Y15 is the start of the first month in 2015 (parameter set by me)
- FEEnd is the End Date of the Person (entered by user)
- e01Y15 is the end of the first month in 2015 (parameter set by me)
- SF is the Annual Salary of the person (entered by user)

I understand that `IF()` has to be changed to `IIF()` and to use `AS` to name the field in the query for the sql code. However, I’m trying to see if I can make some sort of loop so I don’t have to manual change the variables and have 180 line written out. If I have to do that, I will. But I would really rather not.

Is there some way to use a while loop or for loop or some other loop to have MS Access create these 180 columns for me, without having 180 lines of code? Or do I just have to copy and paste a ton?

**DISCLAIMER:** I am using MS Access 2013. Also, I have some experience with VBA code in Excel (and I’m far more comfortable using Excel than MS Access) but am unsure of how to add VBA code to a query (I have added it to my forms).

I also had the idea to change the values of s01Y15 and e01Y15 in each loop but that might be a bit more complicated too so I just have (12*2*5=120) 120 variables set to the start and end dates of every month (which is probably not the best idea in retrospect). Anyways I still cannot get a loop to work in a query (if it even *is* possible).

**EDIT:** Not sure if this is helpful, but this is what I have:

Input data for People Table: 
Person’s name (separated into f/l), Start/End Date (FEStart/FEEnd), Salary (SF).

People Query to show: Person’s name, Start/End Date (FEStart/FEEnd), Salary (SF), & the 180 columns I described above.

Restrictions on Calculations: Fraction of a Month should be a positive number no larger than 1. Year of person starts as a 1 and increases (by one) after each year (essentially infinitely but I am only doing 5 years – so with a max of 5). Monthly salary can be infinite.

Here is an example for an entry in the People table:

FName   | LName | FEStart   | FEEnd     |SF

Anakin  | Skywalker | 7/1/2017  |6/30/2019  |120,000.00

This is a little oversimplified because really the start and end dates are pulled form another table, connected by the “people id”.

Please see the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8uYt9Dj1sUTdU1vVWdOcjNDams) for the calculations.

Comment: A crosstab query may be useful here. Please show sample input data and expected result.

Comment: @Andre please see edits.

Comment: @Andre I tried a a crosstab query but it does not display the info as I would like. I want to see the monthly salary of the person from their start date through their end date. Is there a way I can do this but also factor in partial months (start in the middle of the month, etc.)?